# Does Keycloak support some form of middleman authentication?

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, keycloak, keycloak-gatekeeper

I'm using keycloak to let my users authenticate with my application. And i am trying to migrate some functionality to a few plugins, e.g. a wordpress plugin. For these plugins i want to use a generic solution so I found the following authentication process from Microsoft (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/auth-external-add-ins#middleman-services) and Adobe ( https://adobexdplatform.com/plugin-docs/tutorials/how-to-integrate-with-OAuth/).

I managed to hack my way around the process to get this working with keycloak. But at this moment I'm a bit concerned about the security risk that go with this process.

The process in steps

1. the (plugin) client asks to backend server to generate a code to identify the user.
2. the (plugin) client start polling the backend for an authentication code (no response yet, since the user is not logged in yet).
3. the plugin opens a browser window or tab with the keycloak loginpage. Everything is the same as the normal process, but this time we add an redirect uri with the code generated in step one, which identifies the user.
4. once the user is logged in the user gets redirected in the browser to an endpoint where the code from step one is linked to the access token retrieved in this step.
5. the polling from step 2 now returns the access token to the (plugin) client.

The reason I need to poll for the access token is because I want to make a generic login process for all client.

**In short**, I want to know what the security risks are, given the steps above. Also I can not seem to find any information of keycloak that they want to implement such feature. Does anyone know if they want to implement this, since many other plugins do offer tis feature to authenticate outside the plugin with a popup window and retrieving the accesstoken by "polling" the server.

Thanks for the help.